# How to force RubyMine to reinstall gems it is using for the debugging in the remote environment

Tags: rubymine

I have a project that I deployed to the docker container. Then I configured the remote debugging over ssh in the RubyMine and when I tried to debug the project for the 1st time it installed additional gems (ruby-debug-ide, debase, etc). Then deployed the project into a new container but RubyMine fails to debug new app running in that container b/c it gems are not present there. Is there a way to force RubyMine to reinstall those gems in a new container?

Here is the error I see in the RubyMine when trying to debug the project:

````
Testing started at 10:31 ...
/usr/local/bin/ruby: No such file or directory -- /root/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-2.3.7/bin/rdebug-ide (LoadError)

Process finished with exit code 1
exit status 1```
````

Answer (score 0):

Could you, please, try following:

1. Go to `Settings | Languages and platforms | Ruby SDK and Gems`
2. Select your ssh Ruby SDK and select `Synchronize Gems and RubyMine support files` (down arrow icon above Gems list)
3. After that try to debug your application again

Also, please take a look at our Tutorial: Docker as a remote interpreter﻿
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/using-docker-as-a-remote-interpreter.html

Comment: When I run "Syncronize Gems and RubyMine support files" I am seeing quite a few rsync errors without any real details. In the logs I see entries like "rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/b6051351-c030-11ec-96e9-3e7866fcf3a1/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync/main.c(1404) [receiver=2.6.9]"